# How to invoke NodeJs code from C# MVC?

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net-mvc-4, mqtt

I used mqtt code with nodeJs which runs in console.
But I want to use this nodeJs Mqtt code in c# MVC.
How can I achieve it?

My NodeJs Code as follows,

***Server.js***

```
var mqtt    = require('mqtt');    
var sys = require("sys");   
var stdin = process.openStdin();  
var client  = mqtt.connect('http://broker.mqttdashboard.com');

client.on('connect', function () {  
    console.log("Chat Application");  

    stdin.addListener("data", function(d) {  
        client.publish('presence',d.toString());  
    }); 

    client.subscribe('msg');  

    client.on('message', function (topic, message) {   
        console.log('User2:',message.toString());  
    });  
});
```

***Client.js***

```
var mqtt    = require('mqtt');  
var client  = mqtt.connect('http://broker.mqttdashboard.com');  
var sys = require("sys");  
var stdin = process.openStdin();  

client.on('connect', function () {  
    console.log("Chat Application");  
    client.subscribe('presence');  
}); 

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {  
    console.log('User1:',message.toString());  
});  

stdin.addListener("data", function(d) {  
    client.publish('msg',d.toString());  
});
```

*please give some example code for using nodejs in c# MVC.*

Comment: Do you really want to call out to nodejs code from C# or do you actually want to send/receive MQTT messages from some C# code?

Comment: yes.exactly the same...

Comment: i want to send/recieve mqtt messages using nodeJs from c# code .

Comment: How can i do that???

Comment: Why use nodejs code to send MQTT messages when you could use native C# code?

Comment: My need is to do it in nodeJs Code.thats the reason i am using it.

Answer (score 0):

I Got a solution for this but i want to clarify that this code uses NodeJs or it is a Native c# Code?

```
<script>
       var client = new Messaging.Client("broker.mqttdashboard.com", 8000, "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
        client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
            alert("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage);
        };
        client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
            $('ol').append('<li> ' + $("#TUserName").val() + '  : ' + message.payloadString + '</li><br/>');
        };
        var options = {
            timeout: 3,
            onSuccess: function () {  
            client.subscribe("MQTT/Message", { qos: 2 });
            alert("Connected");
            },
            onFailure: function (message) {
                alert("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
            }
        };
        var publish = function (payload, topic, qos, retained) {
            var message = new Messaging.Message(payload);
            message.destinationName = topic;
            message.qos = qos;
            message.retained = retained;
            client.send(message);
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {
            client.connect(options);
            $("#btn").click(function () {  
                     publish($('#test').val(),"MQTT/Message", 2, true);                                                                                                    
                    $("ol").append("<li> You : " + $("#test").val() + "</li>");
             });

</Script>
```

It works good.
but i want to know is this code uses NodeJs or Not?
Please let me Know.

Comment: this is javascript, and from the script tag and the jQuery syntax i would say, no nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You never directly use `node` in your client side application. But yes, the functionalities can be accessed by making `AJAX` or `XHR` requests to the connection endpoints specified in your `node` application.

**Example**

To access `MongoDb` database in your `javascript` application, you specify some urls or endpoints in your node application which further invokes the callback function. These callback functions contain your code to connect to a `mongo` database.

From the client side, you make an `AJAX` request to the specified url along with the required data. The callback then does the CRUD operations and returns respective result back.

**P.S.** What you wrote in your answer in C# file inside the `<script>` tag is pure `javascript`. Nothing like `Node.Js` in it.